# Left align three columns in Latex

Tags: align

I have an equation in multiple lines. I want to left-align the equations in three columns. How can I do this in Latex?

I am currently using

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&Column1& &Column2&  &Column3 \\
&Column1& &Column2&  &Column3 \\
&Column1& &Column2&  &Column3 \\
\end{equation} 
\end{aligned}
```

However, with the above expression the third column is right-aligned rather than being left aligned.

Here is an example:

`\begin{equation}\label{formula:QPQC}
\begin{aligned}
&\underset{x}{\textbf{Maximize} }&    &x^TFx+2f^Tx &             &             \\
&\textbf{Subject to}             &    &p_i^Tx+p_{i0}\geq 0       &i=1,\ldots,I \\
&                                &    &v_m^Tx+v_{m0}=0           &m=1,\ldots,M \\
&                                &    & x^TQ_zx+2q_z^Tx+q_{z0}=0 &z=1,\ldots,Z   ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}`

Comment: With that input I get left alignment for all three columns. Can you show an example that doesn't?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: You're missing an `&` between the second and third column

Comment: Oh! I forgot! Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @egreg an answer? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an `&` between the second and third column.

Here are some suggestions for avoiding the mistake and for improving the output:

1. give `&&` in pairs next to each other and keep the alignment in the input
2. define macros for “Maximize” and “Subject to”
3. use `\dots` instead of `\ldots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Maximize}[1]{\underset{#1}{\mathbf{Maximize}}}
\newcommand{\Subjto}{\mathbf{Subject\ to}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{formula:QPQC}
\begin{aligned}
&\Maximize{x} && x^TFx+2f^Tx &            &&             \\
&\Subjto      && p_i^Tx+p_{i0}\geq 0      && i=1,\dots,I \\
&             && v_m^Tx+v_{m0}=0          && m=1,\dots,M \\
&             && x^TQ_zx+2q_z^Tx+q_{z0}=0 && z=1,\dots,Z,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]